# php preg_replace string that ends and finishes with slash character

Tags: php, escaping, preg-replace, backslash, slash

dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])

returns in my case : /blabla/test

I am trying a preg_replace so to remove /blabla/.

I do this :

```
$dossier = preg_replace('/^\/[0-9a_z]\/$/','',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

what I hoped to be doing was : "find anything that starts with / and ends with / and has 0-9a-z in between. But this is not how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I noticed in retyping this that you've also got an `a_z` instead of an `a-z`.

Comment: Here's a quick tip for you: In anything like this where you know you will be dealing with slashes, it's often easier to use a different delimiter.  So instead of using a forward slash at the beginning and end of your expression, you could use a tilde for example.  Code like this `/^\/[0-9a-z]+\//` could be changed to look like this `~^/[0-9a-z]+/~`.

Answer (score 1):

Putting that dollar sign in there is throwing off the regex. I believe this is what you're looking for. Let me know if that doesn't work.

```
$dossier = preg_replace('/^\/[0-9a-z]*\//', '', dirname($_SERVER('PHP_SELF']));
```

Comment: this also doesn't work. Strangely, dirname($_SERVER('PHP_SELF')) is /blabla/test ; after the preg replace echo$dossier also is /blabla/test

Comment: ah yeah, forgot the or the asterick rather. trincot's answer may be more appropriate with the +.

Comment: what plus and where?

Comment: Also, for future reference [PHP Regex Live](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) is an amazing site for testing these things out. Even has a little cheat sheet at the bottom.

Comment: Got it ! so it is '/^\/[0-9a-z]*\//'  thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

- You need a hyphen between `a-z`, not an underscore
- You need to allow for more than one such character, by adding a `+`
- You don't want to match the whole string (to be removed), so do not require to match until the end: remove the `$`

So this will do it:

```
/^\/[0-9a-z]+\//'
```